# Compiled vs Install(speed comparation)

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, compiling, source-code, source

I have a quick question because I'm not sure what to think...
When Ubuntu run more fasted? When I've compiled the source code or when I've install it normal? Because I've see and read a lot of comments how said something like "if you will compile the Ubuntu it will run more fasted because it will be made from your CPU". So what do you think guys? That's true? And if yes, the difference between one and another can be so visible? Or can be ignored?

Comment: Install Gentoo and find out for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you compile the source code for your system, it will be faster, as it will be tailored to your system.

When that being said, if you truly want to squeeze every possible resource out of your system, Ubuntu might not be the best choice after all. 
A system like gentoo is a system, where you compile every program for your system, which results in a very specific optimized system.

If you want to know more, take a look at GCC and compile flags